# Qual a diferença entre ~0.0.1 e ^0.0.1 no controle de versão de pacotes do tipo package.json?

Tags: json, npm, packages

Este código é um exemplo:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "gulp": "~0.0.1",
        "browser-sync": "^0.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> De maneira simplificada o TIL (~) aceita somente as *minor version* mais recentes
>   (o número do meio). ~1.2.3 vai aceitar todas as versões 1.2.x mas vai
>   rejeitar 1.3.0.
>
> Já o CIRCUNFLEXO (^) aceita as mais recentes *Major Version* (primeiro número)
>   . ^1.2.3 vai aceitar qualquer release 1.x.x incluindo 1.3.0, mas vai rejeitar as 2.0.0.

[FONTE](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/02/npm-no-longer-defaults-to-tildes/) e link do [Stack em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Answer (score 8):

Resumidamente o uso de til (~) oferece correções de correção de bugs e o circunflexo(^) oferece uma nova funcionalidade compatível com versões anteriores.

Veja essa imagem que encontra-se em [*Semantic Versioning Cheatsheet:*](https://bytearcher.com/goodies/semantic-versioning-cheatsheet/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja uma demonstração na tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referência

- [*Byte Ancher - Semver explained*](https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/)<sup>(en)</sup>